# Can I have Spring Tool Suite and Eclipse at the same time ?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I want to develop my own Spring Boot Application using Spring Tool Suite, but at the moment I am using my Laptop for work where I use Eclipse (I'm working with a big project that is using Spring MVC). I am wondering if there will be complications whenever I start working with my own Spring Boot app using STS.

Comment: STS is based on Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

STS **is** eclipse (actually it's some plugins for eclipse). But, yes. You can have as many eclipse installations as you like; just don't mix workspaces and everything will "just" work. You can also use `m2e` and maven to get spring-boot working with-out the STS plug-ins.